# PHPWord Prevent rows from the same table appearing on different pages

Tags: php, phpword

thanks for help with previous PHPWord issue. I have another.

I'm creating documents with tables where each table is basically used as a stylized container for a list of items. For example, in my case i have a collection of legal definitions. Each definition has a code, title, and textual description that appears in a table. So when there's multiple definitions, each definition has its own table, and appears like so:

[image]

and so on. Each table isnt really a table, its more i'm kind of hijacking tables to stylize my document. The problem is when I have a long list of items, invariably some of the tables will be split between pages where the top row of the table will be at the very bottom of the page and bottom row of the table will be at the very top of the next page, like so

[image]

This is very undesired. Is there any way to tell PHP word that "hey, if this table is going to be split between pages, just put the whole table on the next page" ??

I'm also using PDFmake for making pdf's and it has a pageBreakBefore function that can be used for exactly this purpose. I notice that paragraphs have a pageBreakBefore style which can force each pragraph to appear on a new page, but this isnt what i'm looking for. Is there some way i can maybe get into how PHPWord builds the document to put a conditional test in maybe?

Any input is greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem .... and found the answer today in "normal" MsWord documentation. I found the equivalent in the phpWord doucmentation, tried it and it works:

In your paragraph formats, set 'keepNext' => true